# Suppose $x$ and $y$ are two real numbers such that $x + y = 6$ and $x^2 + y^2 = 43$. Find the value of $x^3 + y^3$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, real-numbers

I tried quadratic and substituting and cubing the equations but it doesn't work and I'm pretty sure i did not make any careless mistake.

Comment: Hint: Find $xy$.

Comment: Please include your work here.  We can determine if you made any mistakes, but do not claim to have tried anything unless you include it in your post.  Else, it's an empty claim.  This site is not intended to be a "do my work for me" service.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

Based on @CalvinLin's comment, we can proceed as follows.

Notice that $x^{3} + y^{3} = (x+y)(x^{2} - xy + y^{2}) = 6(43 - xy)$. Moreover, we also have that
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
(x+y)^{2} = 36\\\\
(x+y)^{2} = 43 + 2xy
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thanks for the help! I got it from the hint and i was pretty close minded with this question. I always have problems realizing spilting the expressions like x^3 + y^3 = (x+y)(x^2-xy+y^2), do u know what can i do to improve that part ? And thanks again

Comment: According to my experience, we get acquainted to the algebraic identities through problem solving. There is a book entitled "Solving problems in Algebra and Trigonometry" by Litvinenko and Mordkovich which is very good for practicing them. I advise you to look for it.

Comment: I will thanks for the help again :))

Comment: You are welcome! I am glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to factor $x^n + y^n$

from $xy = -\frac{7}{2}$ and $x+y = 6$ we know $x,y$ are the roots of
$$ t^2 -6t - \frac{7}{2}  $$

This means that we have a recurrence
$$  T_n = x^n + y^n  $$
which obeys
$$  T_{n+2} = 6 T_{n+1}  + \frac{7}{2} T_n $$

With $T_1 = 6, T_2= 43 $ we get
$$  T_3 = 6 \cdot 43 +  \frac{7}{2} \cdot 6 =  279 $$

the sequence being
$$ 6, 43, 279, \frac{3649}{2}, \frac{23847}{2},  \frac{311707}{4},  \frac{2037171}{4}, \frac{26628001}{8}, $$

Answer (score 1):

The following $2$ facts are very useful generally:

$$x^2+y^2=(x+y)^2-2xy$$
$$x^3+y^3=(x+y)^3-3xy(x+y)$$
Using the first fact, we can easily find the value of $xy$ (using $x^2+y^2=43,~~~x+y=6$), and we already know the value of $x+y$. Hence we can easily find the value of $x^3+y^3$.

If you need any more help please don't hesitate to ask :)

Answer (score 0):

$258 = 6\cdot 43 =(x+y)(x^{2}+y^{2})=x^{3}+x^{2}y+xy^{2}+y^{3}$.

$216 = 6^{3}=(x+y)^{3}=x^{3}+3x^{2}y+3xy^{2}+y^{3}$

Subtracting these equations we get:

$42 = -2(x^{2}y+xy^{2}) \implies -21 = x^{2}y+xy^{2}$ and by substitution we have

$x^{3}-21+y^{3} = 258 \implies x^{3} +y^{3} = 279.$

Comment: The answer is actually 279. Because if u expand (x+y)^3 its not (x+y)(x^2 + y^2) hence not x^3 + xy^2 + x^2y +y^3. I think u did careless there

Comment: Sorry, at the end I subtracted $21$ instead of adding it. I edited my answer.

Comment: Right, but I never equated the expressions, they are distinct as you note. I simply subtracted both sides. To help you see, try expanding them and you will find there is no error in either of them. The first is obvious and for the second I used the binomial theorem.

Comment: Oh i see it was my fault that i mislook but thanks for the clarification !

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

No tricks.  Just solve for $x$ and then $y$:

$x+y=6\iff y=6-x$

$x^2+y^2=43\implies x^2+(6-x)^2=43\iff 2x^2-12x-7=0$

$\iff x=3+\dfrac5{\sqrt2}$ or $x=3-\dfrac5{\sqrt2}$,

with $y=6-x=3-\dfrac5{\sqrt2}$ or $3+\dfrac5{\sqrt2}$, respectively.

Therefore, $x^3+y^3=\left(3+\dfrac5{\sqrt2}\right)^3+\left(3-\dfrac5{\sqrt2}\right)^3$

$=2\times3^3+2\times3\times3\times\left(\dfrac5{\sqrt2}\right)^2=279.$

(Odd powers of $\dfrac5{\sqrt2}$ cancel odd powers of $-\dfrac5{\sqrt2}$.)